# Alignment issue in the Apps, Scripts tabs

Tags: bug, meta, design

There is an alignment issue in the [Apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [Scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) tabs. The user name and the tag are not aligned right indent.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Alignment issue]

Comment: I mentioned it in Chat earlier: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60467432#60467432  not sure if it is a local issue only on our site or across all sites that have the new question list layout.